# How to "repeat" a list of elements in a scroll bar using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to write a mobile application that involves displaying a scrollbar of tools/buttons. When the user scrolls through the list of buttons, I want to repeat that same list again.

To be more clear, let's say I have an array of 10 elements. When I scroll and reach the 10th element, I want to start over displaying the 1st element again. If I scroll the opposite direction past the 1st element, I want to display the last element of the list.

I'm using Ionic 1, and I have just a scrollbar with buttons currently.

```
<ion-scroll
        class="tools"
        direction="x"
        scrollbar-x="false"
        scrollbar-y="false"
        locking="true"
        zooming="false"
        on-scroll="controller.on_scroll()">
        <button
            ng-repeat="tool in model.tools"
            class="button icon {{tool.icon}}"
            ng-click="controller.tool_click(tool.name)"/>
    </ion-scroll>
```

How do I get the buttons in `ng-repeat` to repeat in the way I described above?

Comment: Not sure if a scroll-bar is the right tool for this - a scroll-bar indicates whereabouts in a finite collection you are - but you kind-of wanting an infinite collection (at least presented that way).  More like an image slider type thing, only with buttons?
How should the scroll-bar look when at the end of the items and you want them to start-again?  Should it get smaller?  Move back to the start?

Comment: @PeteGO The scroll-bar isn't actually visible. The appearance is just like an image slider (except buttons) which you suggested. Also, you are perhaps right that a scroll-bar is not what I should be using here. I'm not sure what the appropriate element would be.

Comment: Take a look at the `ion-slide-box`.

Comment: take a look at this plugin: https://github.com/sebelga/ionic-advanced-carousel